# Check if a specific IP address exists on local NIC

Tags: windows, networking, ip, scripting, netsh

I'm looking for a simple script or batch method for checking the existence of a specific IP address (being moved between machines via NETSH) on the local network card. I need to start up certain services / apps etc ONLY if the specified IP address exists on the card.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

powershell?  save this as a .ps1 script and execute.  (substitute the IP address you care about...)

$ipaddr = Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |   Where-Object {$*.IPEnabled -eq $true } |   Foreach-Object { $*.IPAddress }
if ($ipaddr -eq "10.10.10.10") 
{
 "Yes it's here"
 }
 else
 {
 "Nope"
 }

Comment: That's great, I'm finding Powershell extremely useful but have a long way to go in being able to come up with solutions like this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch script that uses `ipconfig`, parses the output for the ip address you specified. Then tells you if it was found or not.

To use it: paste the code into notepad saveas .bat file and execute it.  Change the ip address to the one you want.

```
set ip=192.168.1.1

ipconfig | find /i "%ip%" > nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (echo ip address found) else (echo ip address not found)
```

Comment: Nice and simple when you know how...  thanks very much James - I will give that a try.